# POP3 and IMAP: Setup Gmail & Zoho

Tags: email, imap, gmail, pop3

I wish to use `Gmail` to handle all of my email needs. Sending, reading, deleting, moving, forwarding etc.. I have a domain with an email at `Zoho` `user@mydomain.com`, this is working well.

I've always been confused with `POP3` and `IMAP` regarding which server/client does what. Reading [What's the difference between POP3 and IMAP for e-mail?](https://serverfault.com/questions/61379/whats-the-difference-between-pop3-and-imap-for-e-mail) hasen't really made me any smarter.

Here is a flow of the email from `user@mydomain.com` which I would like:

> Incoming email(to: user@mydomain.com) -> Zoho inbox(user@mydomain.com)
>   -> Gmail account(user@gmail.com) -> Android client/Web browser

I also would like to send:

> Android client/Web browser -> Gmail account(user@gmail.com) -> Zoho
>   account(user@mydomain.com) -> Send email(from: user@mydomain.com)

I would also like to setup so that via Gmail I can send emails via `user@mydomain.com`.

You can say that `Gmail` is central. How would I set this up? I am guessing it is better to use `IMAP` as `POP3` is old. I would also like to keep copies on `Zoho` that are not affected by Gmail, so if I delete a message on Gmail that went to `user@mydomain.com` it would not delete on `Zoho` (use `Zoho` as a backup).

What should be the `IMAP`/`POP3` server in this case?

### Zoho

`POP` Configuration details:

- Incoming server: pop.zoho.com, Port: 995, SSL
- Outgoing server: smtp.zoho.com, Port: 465, SSL

`IMAP` Configuration details:

- Incoming server: imap.zoho.com, Port: 993, SSL
- Outgoing server: smtp.zoho.com, Port: 465, SSL

### Gmail

Incoming Mail (`IMAP`) Server - Requires SSL

- imap.gmail.com
  Port: 993
  Requires SSL:Yes

Outgoing Mail (`SMTP`) Server - Requires TLS

- smtp.gmail.com
  Port: 465 or 587
  Requires SSL: Yes
  Requires authentication: Yes
  Use same settings as incoming mail server

### Incoming vs. Outgoing on Zoho

1. Incoming: Does this mean when Gmail pushes from it's outgoing server to Zohos incoming server?
2. Outgoing: Zoho to push from its outgoing server to Gmails incoming server?

### Incoming vs. Outgoing on Gmail

1. Incoming: Does this mean from my Android client/web browser to push to
   Gmails incoming server?
2. Outgoing: Gmail outgoing server to push to Zohos incoming server?

### **What do I do in Zoho and what do I do in Gmail?**

Comment: https://mailadmin.zoho.com -> Control Panel -> User Details -> Add User. Then add in Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a server configuration question. [Set Gmail to retrieve email from your Zoho account via pop3](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289?hl=en) and to [send mail through Zoho's SMTP server](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html). That's it.

Comment: Thank you, could'nt of asked for a better and more clear answer.